# Git handle deleted

Tags: git, github

Somehow permissions to one of our github handle was removed accidently from main repo yesterday.
A lot of people were using this handle and made branches in which lot of commits were there.

If we give permissions back to this handle, then is it possible that all our branches will also be retrieved?

Comment: I'm thinking this is a bit off-topic for SO. This is not really a programming question, it's more of a support question for GitHub. [example](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13856073/how-to-disable-my-github-account) of similarly closed question.

Comment: i gues this question is entirely different from your example. please read the question carefully before commenting

Comment: Hi Anik, thanks for your comment, but I'm not saying it's a duplicate of the question, or provides an answer, I'm saying it's off-topic. The question I linked was closed for being off-topic. I linked it because it was a question related to GitHub account management; not programming. Similarly, I believe this question is also off-topic, since it is not really a programming question, and a question about GitHub account management. It's also possible I'm not fully understanding your question.

Answer (score 0):

It should be possible: removing permission does not mean removing the branches.
And anyone having cloned that repo should have those branches locally anyway, so the content is not lost (and can be pushed back as a different branch if need be)

Comment: Those branches were present in the forked handle from which permissions were removed. If persmissions are again given to the handle then how do we retrieve those branches since the handle has to again fork the main repo.

Comment: @Anik check with GitHub support if removing the handle meant deleting its associated repos included the fork. If it does, they could have a backup copy of that forked repo.